# Disable el atributo readonly

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un `select` donde selecciono un objecto y este tira el `value` a un `input` , pero quiero preguntar si el texto es igual Otros, que el `input CodArea` pueda ser editable(quitar atributo readonly)

```
<select class="form-control s" id="id_maquinaria" name="" >
    <option value="tshirt"> Camisas</option>
    <option value="pants"> Pantalon </option>
    <option value="other"> Otros</option>
</select>
<?php  echo form_input(['name'=>'CodArea','id'=>'CodArea','class'=>'form-control','readonly'=>'TRUE']);  ?>
```

Aqui mi Javacript

```
$("#id_maquinaria").change(function() {
    var valor = $(this).val(); // Capturamos el valor del select
    var texto = $(this).find('option:selected').text(); // Capturamos el texto del option seleccionado

    $("#CodArea").val(valor);
    $("#maquina").val(texto);
    if ($(this).find('option:selected').text() === 'Otros') {
        $("#CodArea").readOnly = false;
    }
});
```

Espero haberme explicado bien

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dos cosas:

1. Debes usar `.attr("readonly", false)` para remover `readonly`.
2. El texto de tu `option` tiene un espacio al inicio.

Tu código sería así:

```js
$("#id_maquinaria").change(function() {
    var valor = $(this).val(); // Capturamos el valor del select
    var texto = $(this).find('option:selected').text(); // Capturamos el texto del option seleccionado

    $("#CodArea").val(valor);
    $("#maquina").val(texto);
  
    if ($(this).find('option:selected').text() === ' Otros') {
        $("#CodArea").attr("readonly", false); 
    } else {
        $("#CodArea").attr("readonly", true); 
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control s" id="id_maquinaria" name="" >
    <option value="tshirt"> Camisas</option>
    <option value="pants"> Pantalon </option>
    <option value="other"> Otros</option>
</select>
<input name='CodArea' id='CodArea' class='form-control' readonly='TRUE'>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias denuevo!

Comment: disculpa una consulta y si el usuario vuelve a seleccionar otro valor, como activo el `readonly`

Comment: Solo agrega el `else`, ya edite mi respuesta.